# mamp pro, php 7.3.8 and remote mssql server

Tags: php, sql-server

i use mamp pro on mac (catalina) and try to connect to remote mssql server.

in order to work with mssql i installed on the relevant php mamp folder:

```
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools 
pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

than i updated the php.ini file

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

when i try to run (of course with the correct credentails and server name)

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=MY.SERVER;Database=MYDBNAME", "MYUSER", "MYPASS");
```

i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
```

what am i missing?

Comment: As the error says - install the ODBC driver. `pdo_sqlsrv` is the PHP driver, not the actual ODBC database driver.

Comment: isn't it enough to run : sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv . ??

Comment: This is described in [Configure environment for PHP development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-php-development?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thanks, but i already installed  "brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools" that does not seem to help

Comment: No, for any database, not just SQL Server. ODBC is a database protocol. *Something* on the program's side needs to talk with the ODBC driver. All database products provide their own ODBC drivers. You *can* use a generic PHP driver to talk to any ODBC database but that introduces severe restrictions. `pdo_sqlsrv` is a PHP driver that simplifies using the ODBC driver

Comment: `that does not seem to help` in that case post what you actually did - all the steps, not just the last one. Did you check the documentation? In the section [Installing the drivers on macOS Sierra, High Sierra, and Mojave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-the-drivers-on-macos-sierra-high-sierra-and-mojave) . Did you run `sudo pecl install sqlsrv`?

Comment: sure, look at my post, i mentioned it on first that installed sqlsrv

Answer (score 0):

The PHP-PDO driver wants to access MS-SQL-server via the ODBC driver of SQL-server. 
You need to install the [odbc driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.0) by doing

```
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Afterwards, you need to enable TCP connections on sql-server, add a login, add the login to the correct role, and then you need to open port 1433, so TCP connections to SQL-server can work (unless you have both PHP and the sql-server run on the same machine).

And you might have to install UnixODBC:

```
brew install unixodbc
```

Also, you might have to add php_odbc to extensions

```
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

and php-fpm uses another ini file than php-cli/php-cgi.

On ubuntu, the PHP-fpm ini file is in

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

while the other is in

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Another alternative, if you can't get ODBC to work, is to use [PDO_DBLIB](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_DBLIB), which uses FreeTDS instead of ODBC. That might be better anyway.

```
sudo pecl install pdo_dblib
```

However, that restricts you to php > 5.03 < 6.0.0. 
Maybe you can compile it from source.

Mine works on Linux, all I had to do was:

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm php-dev php-pear
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

(msodbcsql17 and mssql-tools I already had installed)

add the lines

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

into both ini files, and done.

Then I executed the [connection-test-sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#testing-your-installation)

```
php ./test.php
```

(i have port 2017, on docker), and it worked:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost,2017";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "database" => "MY_DB_NAME",
    "uid" => "sa",
    "pwd" => "TOP_SECRET"
);

// Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

// Select Query
$tsql = "SELECT @@Version AS SQL_VERSION";

// Executes the query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

// Error handling
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
?>

<h1> Results : </h1>

<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['SQL_VERSION'] . PHP_EOL;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

function formatErrors($errors)
{
    // Display errors
    echo "Error information: <br/>";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ". $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Code: ". $error['code'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Message: ". $error['message'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

> <h1>Results: </h1>
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU16) (KB4508218) - 14.0.3223.3 (X64) 
>     Jul 22 2019 17:43:08    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     
>   Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

I get a [funny warning,](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/736) though:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so' -
>   /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

If I remove

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

then it works, without warning.

**Note:**
Just fixed the crap. 
If you run `php --ini`, it will list you all the ini-files php loads.

The correct location (on Linux) to put these two lines is

```
/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo.ini
```

The above warning occurs if `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` is loaded before `extension=pdo.so`. Also, that way, you only need to set the extension ONCE, and it's done for both php-cli and php-fpm. The mods-available are then (already) symlinked into php-fpm and php-cli.

You might have the same problem on Mac.

To make sure there are no permission issues, create a test user that is sysadmin:

```
-- The available default languages: 
-- SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages AS sysl

CREATE LOGIN [WebServicesTest] WITH PASSWORD = 'TOP_SECRET' 
    ,CHECK_EXPIRATION = off
    ,CHECK_POLICY = off
    ,DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english;


EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember [WebServicesTest], N'sysadmin';
```

To test if the connection is actually working with the user, you can use [AzureDataStudio](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio). 
**Beware:** 
If your system uses OpenSSL 1.1 (e.g. Ubuntu 19.04), you need to download the **insiders-build**.
TDS-based providers (freeTDS/ODBC) need TCP open, even if you work on localhost.

Comment: thank you stefan. i did installed those drivers at first place, and the sql server is working and accept connections on port 1433. but not using php on the MAMP

Comment: @sd1sd1: Another potential source of error is that PHP-FPM (should you use that) uses another php.ini file. I think on Linux it's called php-fpm.ini.  Run "updatedb", then "locate php.ini" (needs locate/mlocate installed)

Comment: unfortunately it's not the php.ini file either, and the php_odcb.dll was already there. thanks a lot for the efforts. most appriciated

Comment: @sd1sd1: Another question, are the files actually called sqlsrv.so and pdo_sqlsrv.so ? Shouldn't they be called sqlsrv.dylib and pdo_sqlsrv.dylib ? Also, which webserver are you using ? apache or something smarter, like nginx ?

Comment: @sd1sd1: Should you not be able to get it to work, you can create a docker image with ubuntu-18.04, and put the php-server there, that should work.

Comment: yes, i couldn't make it work on the mac so i used an ubunut server

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs the answer
turned out need to install one more thing:
brew install msodbcsql@13.1.9.2 mssql-tools@14.0.6.0

Comment: Oh I see, older versions.